# What book do you recommend for a better understanding of Euler Totient function?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

Could anyone recommend a best(simple to read) book for [Euler Totient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) function?

If you have to know, it has been a while, since I introduced myself to this function. So please make sure that the book you are recommending has all the basic staff about this function. I would be very happy if the book includes simplistic proofs that I could understand the proofs by myself.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: If you really know nothing about it read the section in Conway and Guy's *Book of Numbers*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of texts about Euler Totient function. Here are Some of them

1. Elementary Number Theory by Kenneth H. Rosen
2. An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Hardy and wright
3. Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph Gallian

for your information you can download any of this book from [this](http://bookzz.org/) site.

Good luck!